# Problemas al importar módulos en Python

Tags: python, anaconda, pip, python-import

Estoy aprendiendo Python y me encontré con un problema, les escribo para ver si alguién me puede guiar, para darme cuenta que estoy haciendo mal.

Quiero instalar un modulo. en mi terminal cmd dentro de Visual Studio Code ingreso:

pip3 install markdown2

La instalación da ok.
y veo que lo instala en esta ruta: "c:\users\mj\anaconda3\lib\site-packages"

Ahora cuando en la ventana agrego "import markdown2" para utilizarlo, la terminal me avisa que hay un error: "unable to import 'markdown2'"

Mi carpeta de proyecto es "C:\Users\MJ\Desktop\proyect>"

Hace poco instalé anaconda y me da la sensación que quizás se desconfiguro algo que hace que no pueda importar los módulos que instalo.

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: Desde la consola de tu Editor lanza el comando `where python` para ver cual interprete está usando, comprueba que coincida con la instalación de python en la que instalaste la librería, en caso contrario configura el interprete que necesitas en tu Editor.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ingresé el comando y me arrojó:

C:\Users\MJ\anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\MJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
C:\Users\MJ\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

Recién estoy aprendiendo y no se como comprobar que coincida con la instalación de Python en la que instale la librería.

Veo que la ruta donde tengo el proyecto es diferente a la que me dice que se instala la librería. Tengo que corregir eso? En ese caso, desde donde lo debo configurar?

Comment: Usa el comando ``pip list`` para listar los módulos o librerías que tienes instaladas.

Comment: En el terminal del editor puedes usar el comando `pip list` para ver todos los paquetes instalados, si falta la librería que necesitas, el método mas fácil es hacer un `pip install markdown2` ahí mismo.

Comment: Sí, utilicé el comando pip list y figura instalado... Entonces porque cuando lo intento importar para usarlo la terminal me avisa que tengo un error con la importación? El error es: "unable to import 'markdown2' ". Disculpen la ignorancia, pero nunca me había pasado con otras librerías que instale.

Comment: Desde la terminal lanza `python` y luego `help("markdown2")` para ver como importarlo, no todas las librerías se importan con el mismo nombre con el cual se instalan

Comment: al parecer la sintaxis es esta `from markdown2 import Markdown` controla la documentación [aquí](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2)

Comment: Sí había leído la documentación del modulo. y permitía la importación como **import markdown2**. De todos modos, también probé de la manera que indicas y volví a recibir el mismo error. Por eso sospechaba que quizás era un problema de configuración en donde quedó instalado y que por eso no me reconocía como que el modulo existía al llamarlo en el código.

Comment: En vsCode abre una terminal y en ella selecciona cmd para que utilices la terminal de windows. Asegurate que en esta terminal tengas instalado python y la librería en cuestión ejecutando un nuevo cmd y lanzando los comandos que te comenté antes.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda Ariel, ya lo intenté pero sigo con el mismo problema. De todos modos te agradezco por tomarte este tiempo en tratar de darme una mano. Voy a seguir leyendo para ver si encuentro que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, con ubuntu20 y python3.8
copie el archivo markdown2.py al directorio /user/lib/python3.8/importlib/
Abrì nuevamente el editor de texto y chau error.

fijate si en windows tenes algún directo importlib o similar y prueba